# Using negative lookahead Regex in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex, regex-lookarounds

I´m trying to write a regex to select all posts with just two dots in them (..) and discarding all posts that have three or more (..). I have come up with (?

but when i do `SELECT * FROM table where column regexp '(?<!\.)\.{2}(?!\.)'` i get an error. I seems that Mysql doesnt support negative lookahead. How can i fix this?

Comment: Use 2 conditions = first `like '%..%'` and second `not like '%...%'`. With proper quoting, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You may use groups since all you need is a boolean result and the match is searched for only once:

```
SELECT * FROM table where column regexp '([^.]|^)[.]{2}([^.]|$)'
```

**Details**

- `([^.]|^)` - any char but `.` or start of string
- `[.]{2}` - two dots
- `([^.]|$)`  - any char but `.` or end of string

Note that any record containing this substring will be returned even if there are `...` substrings, too, like `abc...bc..`. To avoid those, you may just use

```
SELECT * FROM table where column     LIKE '%..%'
                      AND column NOT LIKE '%...%'
```

`LIKE` requires a full pattern match, so `%` matches any 0 or more chars from the start, `..` or `...` match the two or three dots, and then `%` matches the rest of the string.